# Using javascript code in Jade views - if(variable) shows undefined instead of passing

Tags: templates, node.js, partials, express, pug

So this is a recurring issue I have and haven't found another example on SO so here goes:

When rendering Jade templates I get `'variableName' undefined` even when using `-if(variableName)` in the template.

Example (I'm using this as a partial for 'info' flash messages):

```
-if(info)
  - if(info.length){
   ul
   -info.forEach(function(info){
     li= info
  -})
-}
```

This returns 'info' is not defined instead of not rendering anything when there isn't a flash/info message.  Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

I'm aware of the `typeof(variable) != 'undefined` option as mentioned.  If I wanted to do something like `-if (typeof(req.session.user) != 'undefined')` I would have to do 3 nested `if (typeof(req) != 'undefined'.  Is this my only option?

Comment: Be wary: The 'info' (passed as a parameter name) in function(info) is completely a different 'info' to the one you're using in the if statements. 
This won't fix the problem, but it will make the code more readable.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

try `if(typeof info !== "undefined")`.

I'm not too sure but I think they use `with` to inject variables into the scope of your view.

```
with({}) {
    if (foo) {
         console.log("foo"); // fails foo is not defined.
    }
}

with({}) {
    if (typeof foo !== "undefined") {
         console.log("foo"); // no error
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah, I was aware of that.  I guess I thought there was another solution.  Didn't think everyone was using that.

Comment: If there isn't a slicker way to do this yet, there should be. It seems like a common occurrence in templates.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, most templating engines wrap the entire compiled template function in a with statement. It is possible to do otherwise by taking the variables into account when parsing the template, but I think nearly all templating engines use with().

One solution would be to always make sure "info" is always **in** the locals object when rendering that template. You could do this by explicitly setting info to undefined or any other falsey value.

```
var locals = { info: undefined, ... };
```

Answer (score 0):

simply specify the variable value IF variable undefined:

```
input(name="company[name]" type="text",placeholder="Name",value="#{company.name || ''}")
```

Answer (score -1):

instead of:

```
var params = {
    "info": [
        "a value"
    ]
};

-if(info)
  - if(info.length){
   ul
   -info.forEach(function(info){
     li= info
  -})
-}
```

use:

```
var params = {
    "namespace": {
        "info": [
            "a value"
        ]
    }
};


-if(namespace.info)
  - if(namespace.info.length){
   ul
   -namespace.info.forEach(function(info){
     li= info
  -})
-}
```

Since "namespace" will always exist, and you can reference Object.key without the "undefined" error, this will work better for you.

-jeff